# Multiple-sources dominator trees: compact representation and fast algorithm?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, ds.data-structures, directed-acyclic-graph

I recently learnt about the concept of [dominator trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominator_(graph_theory)) and was fascinated by it.

I was wondering how the problem extends to computing dominators from multiple sources, or even from all vertices in the graph as sources: can all-sources dominators be represented more compactly than in O(n^2) space and computed more efficiently than running the classic dominator tree algorithm from every vertex?

I tried searching for keywords like "multiple sources dominators" etc, but only found about "multiple-vertex dominators", which are a different thing (dominating sets of size > 1)

Does any of this become simpler if the graph is acyclic? (in fact, I work at Google and I think it'd be fun to apply this to the huge dependency graph of Google's [build targets](http://google-engtools.blogspot.com/2011/08/build-in-cloud-how-build-system-works.html))

Comment: I like this question! Intuitively there should be quite a lot of sharing, at least for the dag case. I have, however, a perhaps stupid question: Why would it help to know the dominators of a target in a build system?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's really hard to do that. First of all, for one source dominator tree, there are several dominator points for a vertex. If we want to use "Lengauer-Tarjan algorithm", we can't avoid using tree structure. But how can we save a tree with less than $o(n)$ space? It means that for $n$ source dominator tree, we have to use at least $o(n^2)$ space unless we create a new structure which can represent dominator's information more effective.

For a dag, I remember there is a another algorithm to find whether two vertices share the same dominator for one source. Maybe it will help, you may search uva12671 for more information. (Actually, I am thinking a developing problem about this recently.)

Finally, I am also fascinated by it. If anybody has a new idea, please contact me anytime.

Comment: What does "at least $o(n^2)$" mean? $o(-)$ gives upper bounds so, in effect, you're saying "at least less than $n^2$".

Comment: I'm sorry.It's my fault.I used this from careless .I mean that in the worst case ,we have to use n^2 space.